# (C#) Sending custom ERC20 tokens

Tags: tokens, erc-20, c#

I have the following code

```
var transactionMessage = new TransferFunction
        {
            FromAddress = accountFrom,
            To = accountTo,
            AmountToSend = tokens,
            Gas = new HexBigInteger(gasPrice)
        };

        var tokenService = new Nethereum.StandardTokenEIP20.StandardTokenService(web, accountTo);
        var transferReceipt = await tokenService.TransferAndWaitForReceiptAsync(transactionMessage);

        return transferReceipt.TransactionHash;
```

It works great for sending ETH. However I need to modify it to send custom ERC20 tokens. Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't use Nethereum by myself, but why won't you use such code (taken from [here](https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum/blob/05e97108c1c07e692d032786ac04b4730fe7dba7/src/Nethereum.Contracts.IntegrationTests/CQS/ContractHandlers.cs#L71)):

```
 var transactionMessage = new TransferFunction
 {
      FromAddress = senderAddress,
      To = newAddress,
      TokenAmount = 1000
 };

var transferHandler = web3.Eth.GetContractTransactionHandler<TransferFunction>();
var transferReceipt = await transferHandler.SendRequestAndWaitForReceiptAsync(contractAddress, transactionMessage);

var transaction = await web3.Eth.Transactions.GetTransactionByHash.SendRequestAsync(transferReceipt.TransactionHash);
var transferDecoded = transaction.DecodeTransactionToFunctionMessage<TransferFunction>();
```

TransferFunction is defined [here](https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum/blob/05e97108c1c07e692d032786ac04b4730fe7dba7/src/Nethereum.Contracts.IntegrationTests/CQS/ContractHandlers.cs#L159):

```
[Function("transfer", "bool")]
public class TransferFunction : FunctionMessage
{
    [Parameter("address", "_to", 1)]
    public string To { get; set; }

    [Parameter("uint256", "_value", 2)]
    public int TokenAmount { get; set; }
}
```

There are also examples of getting token balance.

Comment: I could have swore I tried something similar before. Thanks a lot!